# How to transform maximum distances between two graphs into cross-over and vice-versa?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-methods, time-series

Considering there are have two series v1,v2 over time which ranges between 0 and 1. Two graphs are plotted below in colour Blue and Green and the pattern between the graphs is shown in the diagram.How can I transform the maximum distances between the points into cross-overs and vice versa?

[image]

Comment: Do you have more conditions on what the data should look like? I.e. are both graphs piecewise linear? There are a lot of different ways to do what you are looking for, so if you add why you are trying to do this it will help you to get a good answer.

Comment: The thing is I donot know how the data can look like..its beyond my boundary..the data bears the pattern as I have shown in the above image. Why I am trying to do this is I want to keep track of how many times the two lines went apart and came back

Comment: @TylerChen does the explanation help? Or you need more information?

Comment: Yes that it helpful, but I'm not sure that having the second graph will make this easier. Have you considered looking for the zeros of $f(x) - g(x)$. If the data looks like this, then every zero corresponds to the lines going apart and coming back together.

Comment: Yes I have looked at the Zeros of f(x)-g(x) but it gives the cross overs in the First Graphs

Comment: Yes, but every crossover in the first graph corresponds to the graphs went apart and came back (at least if the data looks like you've drawn). So to count the number of times the data goes apart and comes back is the same as counting the number of times it crosses.

Comment: every time the data goes apart there isn't a cross over.There might be 5-6 times data goes apart comes together and then there is one cross over...so counting the cross over from the first graph wouldn't give the correct ans

Comment: I see. You could try to find the extrema of the difference then. Using a find peaks function, or by taking the derivative.